# Solaris: detect hotswap SATA disk insert

Tags: solaris, zfs, sata, hp-smart-array, hotswap

What's the method used on Solaris to get the system to rescan for new disks that have been hot-plugged on a SATA controller?

I've got an HP X1600 NAS which had 9 drives configred in a ZFS pool. I've added 3 disks, but the `format` command still only shows the original 9.

When I plugged them in, I saw this:

```
cpqary3: [ID 823470 kern.notice] NOTICE:  Smart Array P212 Controller
cpqary3: [ID 823470 kern.notice]  Hot-plug drive inserted, Port=1I Box=1 Bay=12
cpqary3: [ID 479030 kern.notice]  Configured Drive ? ....... NO
cpqary3: [ID 100000 kern.notice]
cpqary3: [ID 823470 kern.notice] NOTICE:  Smart Array P212 Controller
cpqary3: [ID 823470 kern.notice]  Hot-plug drive inserted, Port=1I Box=1 Bay=11
cpqary3: [ID 479030 kern.notice]  Configured Drive ? ....... NO
cpqary3: [ID 100000 kern.notice]
cpqary3: [ID 823470 kern.notice] NOTICE:  Smart Array P212 Controller
cpqary3: [ID 823470 kern.notice]  Hot-plug drive inserted, Port=1I Box=1 Bay=10
cpqary3: [ID 479030 kern.notice]  Configured Drive ? ....... NO
```

But can't figure out how to get the `format` command to see them so I know they've been detected by the system.

Comment: Did you configure multiple RAID 0 drive arrays, or did you configure a hardware RAID 1,5,1+0 on the P212 controller?

Comment: I don't believe I configured the P212 at all - I use ZFS so like to see the individual disks as they are so that Solaris can manage them. The only array created is the two 2.5" system disks in the back are in RAID1 on the controller. How would I go about checking how the P212 is configured from within Solaris?

Comment: Have a look at the [Array Configuration Utility](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19253-01/816-5177/6mbbc4g3m/index.html) documentation

Comment: Thanks - I ended up having to reboot and add the disks manually as individual RAID0 volumes in the P212 bios. Next time, I'll dig into it a bit more and figure out how to configure it from the CLI.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the [devfsadm](http://manpages.unixforum.co.uk/man-pages/unix/solaris-10-11_06/1M/devfsadm-man-page.html) command

`devfsadm -c disk`

```
 The default operation is to attempt to load every driver  in
 the  system  and  attach  to  all possible device instances.
 Next, devfsadm creates logical links to device nodes in /dev
 and /devices and loads the device policy.
```

Comment: I tried this, but I still only see the 9 disks (+ 1 system volume = 10) in format. I'm starting to think that the Smart Array isn't presenting them to the OS properly for some reason.

Comment: This works, once I'd actually bothered to add the disks as Volumes in the P212 controller.

Comment: Just adding what I just googled -- on some distributions, you need `cfgadm`, in my case it was `cfgadm -c configure sata3/3`.

Comment: This also works like a charm when hotplugging/adding virtual disks in VMware ESXi (useful for testing purposes).

Answer (score 2):

You may need to run `/usr/sbin/devfsadm` first.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the post at:
[Disabling RAID feature on HP Smart Array P400](https://serverfault.com/questions/29349/disabling-raid-feature-on-hp-smart-array-p400)

Be careful with the SmartArray single-disk RAID 0 setup. If you have a hotplug event (disk failure/drive removal), ZFS won't recognize the new disk without a reboot. The Smart Array controllers don't offer a true JBOD setting.

You're best off using a more compatible controller:
[ZFS SAS/SATA controller recommendations](https://serverfault.com/questions/84043/zfs-sas-sata-controller-recommendations)