# How to make Solaris rescan disk info after hotswap?

Tags: solaris, sata, hotswap, smartos, illumos

I'm running a SmartOS-based ZFS NAS, with a bunch of SATA disks directly connected to [the logic board](http://www.supermicro.com/products/motherboard/xeon3000/x58/x8ste.cfm) (no fancy disk controller / backplane or anything).

A 1.5 TB disk in my zpool recently failed.  `iostat` says:

```
# iostat -En c2t5d0
c2t5d0           Soft Errors: 0 Hard Errors: 8 Transport Errors: 21 
Vendor: ATA      Product: ST31500341AS     Revision: SD17 Serial No: [...]
Size: 1500.30GB <1500301910016 bytes>
Media Error: 0 Device Not Ready: 0 No Device: 0 Recoverable: 0 
Illegal Request: 89040 Predictive Failure Analysis: 0
```

I hotswapped the disk with a new 2.0 TB disk, yet `iostat` still says the same thing — `Size: 1500.30GB`.

How can I tell the system to rescan the disk so it identifies the correct disk size?  (I'd like it to probe the correct size so I can eventually expand my zpool.)

---

#### Already tried

1. `devfsadm -c disk` as suggested on [a similar question](https://serverfault.com/a/247695/6715) — no effect.
2. `cfgadm -c configure sata0/5::dsk/c2t5d0` — it just says `Device already configured`; no effect.

Answer (score 3):

You need to first initiate devfsadm cleanup subroutines.

```
# devfsadm -C -c disk -v
```

Then, configure and create device path

```
# devfsadm -c disk -v
```

If that is unsuccessful, then...

Remove the disk.

```
# cfgadm -c unconfigure sata0/5::dsk/c2t5d0
```

Initiate devfsadm cleanup subroutines.

```
# devfsadm -C -c disk -v
```

Verify the disk has been removed.

```
# cfgadm -al
# ls -ld /dev/dsk/c2t5d0*
```

Configure and create device paths

```
# devfsadm -c -v
# cfgadm -c configure sata0/5::dsk/c2t5d0
```

Verify the disk

```
# cfgadm -al
# ls -ld /dev/dsk/c2t5d0*
```