# Turn off RAID on HP DL380?

Tags: raid, hp, software-raid

Can anyone tell me how I can turn RAID off on a DL380-G5.  I just want the disks connected directly without any RAID as I want to use this to test Microsoft's software RAID.  Can't seem to find anything in the BIOS to do this.

Comment: It's not possible. Please use an LSI SAS controller in place of the smartarray.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. For each drive you'll need to create one array with one raid0 logical drive.

Comment: [[citation-needed]]

Comment: http://h18004.www1.hp.com/products/quickspecs/14328_na/14328_na.pdf All options are Smart Array controllers. Read all of http://www.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c00709035.pdf See no mention of JBOD config.

Comment: Creating multiple RAID-0 logical drives is not an ideal solution to this issue. There's an upper-limit on the number of logical drives (this disks) that can be configured on a controller. Also, the failure of a drive means that a logical volume has failed. This can cause device renaming/reordering issues and kills the ability to hot-plug devices.

Comment: Thanks. Just wanted to make sure you weren't talking out your arse.

Answer (score 2):

[This is not possible](https://serverfault.com/questions/84043/zfs-sas-sata-controller-recommendations?lq=1). Please use an LSI SAS controller in place of the HP Smart Array RAID controller.

Please see:

[Disabling RAID feature on HP Smart Array P400](https://serverfault.com/questions/29349/disabling-raid-feature-on-hp-smart-array-p400/41975#41975)

[ZFS SAS/SATA controller recommendations](https://serverfault.com/questions/84043/zfs-sas-sata-controller-recommendations?lq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the drives are physically connected to the RAID controller, you would typically go into the BIOS setup for the controller itself (not the server) and specify each individual device as a JBOD (Just a Bunch of Disks).  Specify them individually, not altogether or you may end up with multiple drives appearing as one huge drive (without the mirroring, striping, parity you would get from RAID).